# Case escalation - does the IsEscalated field ever go back to false?

Tags: case-object

We have some escalation rules setup and also field tracking on the Escalated field. But though a case is updated to not meet escalation criteria after the first level of escalation, I've never seen the `IsEscalated` field turn to false.

Does it happen? Does a case remain escalated always once it is escalated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the case remains escalated. This is the default behaviour.

However, you can have a workflow or trigger which changes the `IsEscalated` field back to `false` based on some condition. I've tried this just now.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Salesforce default behaviour has now changed - If a case is updated to no longer meet the criteria of the escalation, the case de-escalates. This behaviour has been confirmed by Salesforce support as expected.

Comment: is there a documentation link they provided?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However, this can be confirmed by testing in our org. If a case no longer meets the criteria of an escalation rule, the escalation rules return "false" when re-evaluated and the case is de-escalated. However, If anybody is seeing different behaviour, that would be really interesting to hear about.